# Find a basis in $\Bbb{C}^{(2\times 2)}$ over $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\Bbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers

Exercise: Find a basis of the vector space $\Bbb{C}^{(2 \times 2)}$ over $\Bbb{C}$ and show that it is actually a basis.

I need some help to understand it.

For example i think to choose 4 Matrices .

1 0     |   0  1    |     0    0   |   0   0

0 1     |   0  0     |    1    0    |   0   1

Comment: Is $\mathbb{C}^{(2\times2)}:=M_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: First, give some examples (3 or 4) of elements in $\Bbb{C}^{(2 \times 2)}$

Comment: i think that first i should choose 4 Matrices:

Comment: Surely this exercise is similar to ones that were previously worked in your class materials or lectures.  Do you know the definition of a basis?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to prove that for any field (even a unital ring) $K$, the following form a basis to $M_2(K)$:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Another way: try to prove that $M_2(K)\cong K^4$ as vector spaces, then look at the image of the basis elements of $K^4$ in $M_2(K)$

Comment: Thanks that what i also thought .

Answer (score 0):

In Or's answer he says what the basis should be. But you still need to show that it's a basis, which has two parts: spanning and linear independence. To show they span, you need to show how a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$ can be written as a linear combination of those 4 matrices. Then for linear independence, you start with a linear combination of the 4 matrices and ask how you can get the zero matrix. Combine the linear combo into a single matrix to see that the coefficients in the combination have to be all zeros.

Comment: I can clearly prove that it is linear independent ,but i have a question regarding to the part that i should show that they span .How can i show this except the method that the determinant of the matrix should be nonzero and it clear that it is 1.But is there any other way to prove that they span?

Comment: @yaman : Pick an arbitrary matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \text{.}  $$  Now show that this is in the span of your basis by writing it as a $\Bbb{C}$-linear combination of the four basis matrices.